# How to jump to the bottom of the terminal input history after a long lookback?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I usually browse my terminal history really far into the past by pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> key to to find something, and after I got that I would like to go to the bottom of the input history, to the now empty new command (is there a word for this?) to enter my new command, but I don't want to press <kbd>↓</kbd> a gazillion times. I also don't want to delete a row in the history with backspace or something else.

I'm looking for something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> in text editors or something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the terminal but it should jump the input and not the output history.

I wrote terminal because I'm interested in the Linux/Windows/OSX solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, pretty much anywhere in Linux/Unix/OSX that you have a command history (e.g. bash), that's probably powered by the Readline library.

Readline has its own set of commands that get linked to keyboard shortcuts, and one of the [history manipulation commands](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_15.html) is `end-of-history` which is exactly what you're looking for.

The default keybinding is `M->`, or, <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>. On most Linux setups, <kbd>Meta</kbd> is usually bound to the Windows key, so typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> will probably work. If not, or you're on OSX, typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>></kbd> will probably work.

Comment: I tested the OSX version and it works. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can only comment for Windows systems, running WSL on Windows Terminal, but what worked for me was:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>)

…rather than the Super/Meta/Windows key-based shortcut discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 21.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> worked for me.